# Deleting a line from a text file in VB08

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a program with a list box that displays text from a selected text file. I have already made it to delete the item from the listbox but I don't know how to get it to delete that same line from the text file so it doesn't just display it again when you reopen the dialog. Any help? I am using streamwriter and streamreader. I can also TeamView if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and in most cases best approach is to overwrite the whole file. So you you want to delete all lines that are no longer in the `ListBox`?

```
Dim resultLines = From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
             Join item In lb.Items On item.ToString Equals line
             Select line
IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, resultLines)
```

This reads all lines from the file and joins them with the not deleted items in the `ListBox`. The resulting lines are written back to the file.

Comment: I tried using the code you wrote but it was giving me errors with the "Join Item" part. I was think that I can just have the items from the listbox be set as the text of a textbox and then have it empty the text file and write down what is in the textbox BUT I cannot get the items to be set as the text. I have tried using

Comment: textboxx2.text = listbox1.text

But nothing

Comment: @ZackSaysVoteRonPaul: **What _errors_ do you get?** Which .NET framework version are you using? Why do you want the unnecessary extra step with the TextBox? Anyway, [`ListBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.text.aspx) returns the text property of the currently selected item, not of all items.

Comment: The data is encrypted from the textbox and then added to the text file for storage. I am not sure which version I am running anymore. I couldn't tell you the last time I downloaded it lol

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to re-write the file using the contents of the listbox. You didn't specify any mapping from the text file to the listbox, so I can't give more detail.